# IHTMLSelectElement : not returning dynamically added items

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc

- I have added a `ComboBox` to my `CHTMLEditCtrl` by passing it in a HTML string.
- Then dynamically I add the members(items) to it using IHTMLSelectElement.
- Now I want to change the font of one of the items that I have just added.

But when I use item() method on this object, *it returns a **null***.  Also when I use `get_size` on the Object, it returns 0, even though all the items I added in the combobox are visible(and hence I infer all the items are added).

I am not able either to retrieve it using COM methods. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the DOM elements are available once the page render is complete.

Comment: So what should I do. I tried to do a Post Message but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi it has started working. I was using SelectObject instead of ElementOption.